# Ubuntu 18.04 freezes after logging in?

Tags: 18.04, gnome, xorg, wayland

I have the log in "page" where I can change between:

- GNOME
- GNOME Classic
- GNOME on Xorg
- Ubuntu
- Ubuntu on Wayland

Some of them are freezing right after logging in.
Ubuntu on Wayland works but crashes.
GNOME and GNOME Classic - I don't like them.

Please advise how can I make it work normally?

My graphics card is Intel corporation UHD Graphics 620 (rev 07).

Comment: what is the exact error message?

Comment: @TimothyTruckle there isn't, it just crashes sometimes with Wayland and on others it just freezes and I can't move my mouse or use keyboard.

Comment: Type journalctl -e to see logs.